# Multi rename in Linux bash

Tags: linux, bash

I trying to rename my file(date yesterday)1, file(date yesterday)2,3,4,5... using this code.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo dir date?
read datedir
cd /mnt/c/Users/OPS\ 1/Desktop/F/CVS/CVS\ COMPONENTS/CVS$datedir
echo date now?
read datetd
echo last date?
read lastdate
rename -v 's/$lastdate/$datetd/g' *$lastdate
```

Comment: please elaborate you question.

Comment: already elaborate sir, sorry im noob in english

Comment: What is your question? Doesn't it work? If not, what do you expect vs. what do you actually see?

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly that you have a set of files (Eg. file201811011 file201811012 ...) assuming 20181101 is the date of yesterday, and you want to rename them? If this is the case, into what do you want to rename them? Or do you want to move them? Please give an example. Eg. I have `/path/to/file201811011` that should become `/path/to/20181101/file1` (this is just an example, not necessarily what you ask)

Comment: Please describe clearly what you want (not only your current attempt). E.g.: 1) list all files with their intial name, 2) list all files with their desired name after renaming.

Comment: I'm trying to rename all file using bash
e.g
file1-11-09-18
file2-11-09-18
file3-11-09-18
file4-11-09-18

Comment: @FrankBalos Okay, so now we know how the files look like, but you want to rename them into what?

Comment: @FrankBalos and don't worry about the English. Not everybody is native. We will do our best to help you nonetheless. I would advise you to slightly [edit] your question and provide the information we request. This is: (a) which OS are you running on? (b) how do your original filenames look like (c) after renaming, how do you want the filenames to look like. (See [ask] and [mcve])

Comment: @kvantour i want to change it into new date for example

file1-11-09-18
file2-11-09-18
file3-11-09-18

change it to

file1-11-10-18
file2-11-10-18
file3-11-10-18

using my bash.

I've been search for google about bash input and output and multi rename in linux and this is the result.

Comment: @FrankBalos: On the Stack Overflow we want to have all information, needed for understanding the problem, **in the question post**. Please, [edit] your question post and add details into it. Comments are mainly for *requesting* more information about the problem, but that information should appear in the *question post*.

Answer (score 0):

After reading **`man rename`** I see what you are trying to do:

Your `rename` command is used wrong. Update it with the following:

```
rename "$lastdate" "$datetd" *$lastdate
```

> SYNOPSIS: `rename from to file...`
>
> DESCRIPTION: `rename` will rename the specified files by replacing **the first occurrence** of `from` in their name by `to`.
>
> **<sub>source: `man rename`</sub>**

Comment: error: Illegal octal digit '8' at (user-supplied code), at end of line